# Unicode Character is not Not Displaying Correctly When Exporting To Excel

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, excel, unicode, font-awesome

I have some javascript code to export html data to a spreadsheet (xls). Everything is working just fine, however when I open up the Excel file the Unicode character shows up as a filled black circle. All other data displays correctly.

The circle shows up perfectly on my page:

[image]

However, when I download the Excel file the color of the circle doesn't show up. It shows up like this:

[image]

This is the code that I'm using to display the Unicode character:

```
<td><span class="@circle">&#x25CF;</span></td>
```

Like I said before, it works just fine on my app page but when I download the Excel file it turns black.

Also, I found out that if I add a color to the span style it shows up perfectly on the Excel sheet. For example if I use this, it works:

```
<td><span class="@circle" style="color:green;">&#x25CF;</span> </td>
```

[image]

I do need to use the @circle variable because I have a method that grabs the color depending on the data.

circle = SharedMethods.getColor(data.ID, data.Value);

I also tried using the FontAwesome icon instead of the Unicode character but that didn't work either! It didn't even display the icon on the spreadsheet.

Do any of you guys have an idea on how to fix this? Any help is very much appreciated!

Should I add more details to my question?